# Programatically set frame size of labels inside UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton, frame

I have a custom UIButton that I created. Inside the button I have 2 labels, one above the other. The top one is the title so it is a little bigger, and the bottom one is a bit smaller. 
My goal is to have both labels cover the whole button exactly, like this:
The top label will cover the top 2/3 part of the button, and  the bottom will cover the rest  1/3 of the button. 
My goal is not far from being reached, but I get weird behavior - the labels are a little out of the button, and in some cases they disappear(I can click on the button but cannot see the labels).
This is my custom UIButton for reference, I hope this code will help people regardless to my issue:

```
class ButtonWithStats: UIButton {

var num: Int
var name: String
var nameLabel: UILabel?
var numLabel: UILabel?
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   // fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    self.num = 0
    self.name = ""

    self.numLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)) //just to init the labels.
    self.nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
    self.numLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    self.nameLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    self.numLabel?.textColor = UIColor.purple
    self.nameLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    self.numLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 11)
    self.nameLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: 13)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func setButton(numInput: Int, nameInput: String){
    self.num = numInput
    self.name = nameInput
    self.setLabels()
}

private func setLabels(){

    numLabel?.text = String(self.num)
    nameLabel?.text = self.name
    let widthForName = self.frame.width
    let heightForName = self.frame.height * 2 / 3
    nameLabel?.center = self.center
    nameLabel?.frame = CGRect(origin: self.frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: widthForName, height: heightForName))
    let widthForNum = self.frame.width
    let heightForNum = self.frame.height * 1 / 3
    let yForNum = (self.frame.height * 2 / 3) //+ self.frame.origin.y
    numLabel?.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x, y: yForNum, width: widthForNum, height: heightForNum)
    self.addSubview(nameLabel!)
    self.addSubview(numLabel!)
    print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
    print("Button \(self.nameLabel?.text) frame is: \(self.frame)")
    print("Label frame is: \(self.nameLabel?.frame)")
    print("Num frame is: \(self.numLabel?.frame)")
    print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@")
}
}
```

my console prints this data:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Button Optional("button one") frame is: (257.5, 0.0, 64.5, 33.0)
Label frame is: Optional((257.5, 0.0, 64.5, 22.0))
Num frame is: Optional((257.5, 22.0, 64.5, 11.0))
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Button Optional("Button two") frame is: (129.0, 0.0, 64.0, 33.0)
Label frame is: Optional((129.0, 0.0, 64.0, 22.0))
Num frame is: Optional((129.0, 22.0, 64.0, 11.0))
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Button Optional("Button three") frame is: (0.0, 0.0, 64.5, 33.0)
Label frame is: Optional((0.0, 0.0, 64.5, 22.0))
Num frame is: Optional((0.0, 22.0, 64.5, 11.0))
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than add 2 labels, how about setting the `numberOfLines` on the `UIButtons`'s `textLabel`?

```
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
```

Or alternatively, add a vertical `UIStackView`, with the 2 labels as subviews, and set `stackView.frame = button.bounds`

```
let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [numLabel, nameLabel])
stackView.frame = buttonView.bounds
addSubview(stackView)
```

You can adjust the `stackView.spacing` / `layoutMargins` etc, to position the labels as required

To make the `numLabel` twice the height of the `nameLabel`, you could use set constraints using…

```
numLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameLabel.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2)
```

I'd recommend you do this in a storyboard / xib, but if you need to do it programatically, you might find it useful create a xib to experiment with the `UIStackView` settings.

Comment: How would you set the sizes to be 2/3 and 1/3 using a stack view?

Comment: Now everything constraints wise is perfect, the problem is that the button is not clickable! any idea why?

Comment: oK, solved it by adding this line:         stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
 for some reason the stackView has user interaction enabled so it blocked the buttons interaction.